# using listdata only and get from another model in Yii

Tags: yii

can i just have listdata by itself? The list doesn't list anything, all I keep getting is "Array" as the return.

I have:

```
$awards= $model->findAll('uid='.$uid);
return CHtml::listData($awards, 'award_id', '$data->award->name');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$awards= $model->findAll(array('condition'=>'uid ='.$uid)); // get records from table

return CHtml::listData($awards, 'award_id', 'award_name'); // third parameter should the array value. Most of the case we use to display in combo box option text.
```

If you are getting from another table, then declare a variable in your award model.

```
public $awrd_name;
```

Then you have to get records using relation in criteria.

Output will be :

```
array("1" => "award1", "2" => "award2", "3" => "award3");
```

refer this link : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29837-show-two-table-fields-in-dropdownlist/

Comment: thanks, but the 3 parameter i am trying to get it from another table which has that name

Comment: hmm i still have the same issue.. returns "Array".

Comment: what are you expecting instead of array?

Comment: if you want string, then you can implode the array. if dropdown, you can pass the returning array as 3rd parameter in dropdown function.